# Backup GCS bucket to an archive-class GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The [GCS Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service) is a nice solution for regular transfer of data.  What would the appropriate settings be to sync a bucket to another, where the destination bucket has the archive storage class?

One of my concerns is possible expensive operations on archive class objects, if the service is checking for identical objects.  If, to avoid these checks, I just copy files daily that are new within the last 24 hours, how accurate is that timing -- can I miss a file due to timing jitter of several minutes on job start?

Answer (score 2):

While "the appropriate settings" would completely depend on your business needs. A good approach could be to use a Cloud Function triggered on create/finalize on your standard bucket that creates a copy of that object in your second bucket.

You can use this function in python as a guide:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage.blob import Blob

def hello_gcs(event, context):
    client = storage.Client()
    source_bucket = client.get_bucket("my_source_bucket)
    dest_bucket = client.get_bucket("my_destination_bucket")
    filename = str(event['id']).rsplit('/',1)[0]
    blob = Blob.from_string("gs://" + filename)
    source_bucket.copy_blob(blob,dest_bucket)
```

Comment: I like the alternative approach of forgoing the transfer service.  Is it any more or less costly for the transfer?  Also, what happens if a file is overwritten in the source -- does it incur an early deletion on the destination side (or can object version save us here?)?

Comment: as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#archival-pricing)"Early deletion charges apply when you overwrite or move an existing object before the minimum storage duration, because both actions delete the original file" This function as it is will rewrite the file in your destination bucket if the file is rewrite on the original bucket. You can still append the version of the object to the name in your archive bucket if you need so, avoiding checking reading files on the destination bucket at all.

Comment: Regarding "it is any more or less costly for the transfer? If you sync your buckets with the transfer services it will read all your objects in the destination bucket, which I understand that can really expensive since is archive class. My approach avoid this but you will have to take in account the aditional expenses of Cloud Functions and [compare the prices](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) by yourself